# Can't get to know the size of a standard JButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

In one window I added a JButton to a Panel within a BorderLayout. In other window, using the same fashion, I added a JButton to one of the "cells" of a TableLayout. The first button is of the standard size and the second button is not. So I was trying to get to know the size of the first one so that I could set the same size for the other one. Unfortunately, running this code:

```
nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
System.out.println(nextButton.getWidth());
System.out.println(nextButton.getHeight());
nextButton.setSize(150, 100);
System.out.println(nextButton.getWidth());
System.out.println(nextButton.getHeight());
```

(tried on both buttons) gave the following output:

- 0
- 0
- 150
- 100

Moreover, the setSize method had no visible effect at all. Do have any idea what's wrong here?

**--EDIT--**
  revalidate() method does not work

**--EDIT 2--**
`nextButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));` results in even more mess: for both windows I got all zeros as the result of the System.out.println statements and there is a visible change of the button's size in the first window, but still nothing for the second one.

Comment: Your components/buttons have no size until they have been rendered. Consider nesting each JButton in its own JPanel and then adding the JPanel into the TableLayout as one possible solution.

Comment: Also, most layouts respect the preferredSize, not the size, so often you will need to call setPreferredSize, not setSize. I'm not familiar with the TableLayout though.

Comment: The effective size of the button will depend on the font size, and the text on it. And the chosen Look and Feel.

Comment: I didn't change anything about the font size and the Look and Feel. The text is same for both buttons ("NEXT"), so the buttons should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I was trying to get to know the size of the first one so that I could set the same size for the other one

```
button2.setPreferredSize( button1.getPreferredSize() );
```

Comment: Perfect! The result is: java.awt.Dimension[width=64,height=26]. Thank you!

Comment: +1 agreed, PrefferedSize or already visible Component can returns Size

Answer (score 1):

Try `nextButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100))`.